# ListSelectionListener, ventana JFrame se abre dos veces

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, jtable

tengo una tabla de preguntas con 4 columnas; pregunta, autor, cantidad de respuestas y fecha de publicación. Añadí un ListSelectionListener, para que al apretar una de las filas, se abra una ventana mostrando más información acerca de la pregunta, sin embargo se abren dos ventanas a la vez, es decir, al clickear una fila, se abren dos ventanas, que son iguales(que muestran la información correctamente). No logro encontrar el error dentro del código. Solo quiero que se abra una ventana, no dos repetidas. A continuación comparto lo realizado. Gracias de antemano.

```
package Lab4.views;

import Lab4.controllers.StackController;
import Lab4.models.Pregunta;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnswerView extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //atributos de la clase AnswerView
    private StackController stack;
    private String[][] matriz;
    private List<Pregunta> listaPreguntas = new ArrayList<>();
    private JLabel label1;
    private JTable tableQuestions;
    private JButton buttonReturn;

    public AnswerView(StackController stack, List<Pregunta> listaPreguntas) {
        super("Stack Overflow");
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //ventana al centro de la pantalla
        setListaPreguntas(listaPreguntas);
        setSize(500, 530); //tamaño de la ventana
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.stack = stack; //stack que es recibido como parámetro
        setResizable(false); //no se puede cambiar el tamaño de la ventana
        initComponent(); //se inicializan los atributos relacionados a la clase
    }

    private JFrame getFrame() {
        return this;
    }

    public void setListaPreguntas(List<Pregunta> listaPreguntas) {
        this.listaPreguntas = listaPreguntas;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        this.dispose(); //se vuelve a la ventana de opciones
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        matriz = new String[stack.getListaPreguntas().size()][4];
        String[] nombreColumnas = {"Pregunta", "Autor", "Respuestas", "Fecha de publicacion"};
        tableQuestions = new JTable(matriz, nombreColumnas);
        label1 = new JLabel("Seleccione una de las siguientes preguntas para ver mas informacion: ");
        buttonReturn = new JButton("Volver al menu");
        //modificar el tamaño de las celdas
        TableColumn columna = tableQuestions.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        columna.setPreferredWidth(350);
        columna = tableQuestions.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        columna.setPreferredWidth(150);
        columna = tableQuestions.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        columna.setPreferredWidth(200);
        columna = tableQuestions.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        columna.setPreferredWidth(300);

        //se define el contenido de la tabla
        for (int i = 0; i < listaPreguntas.size(); i++) {
            matriz[i][0] = listaPreguntas.get(i).getTitulo();
            matriz[i][1] = listaPreguntas.get(i).getAutor();
            matriz[i][2] = String.valueOf(listaPreguntas.get(i).getRespuesta().size());
            matriz[i][3] = String.valueOf(listaPreguntas.get(i).getFecha());
        }

        add(label1);
        add(tableQuestions);
        add(new JScrollPane(tableQuestions));
        add(buttonReturn);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        buttonReturn.addActionListener(this);


        tableQuestions.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                String title = tableQuestions.getValueAt(tableQuestions.getSelectedRow(),0).toString();
                for(Pregunta p: stack.getListaPreguntas()) {
                    if(p.getTitulo().equals(title)){
                        QuestionView questionWindow = new QuestionView(p, stack);
                        questionWindow.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Tal vez es porque no estas usando una propiedad `boolean` del evento `ListSelectionEvent` que se llama `getValueIsAdjusting`... Intenta colocar todo el código del método `valueChanged` dentro de una condición:  `if(e.getValueIsAdjusting())`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, he añadido la condición dentro del método valueChanged y ahora me aparece una sola ventana.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puede (y debe) estar pasando es que la lista que devuelve el método `stack.getListaPreguntas())` contenga las preguntas duplicadas o con el mismo título y por ende esta comprobación dentro del `for` `p.getTitulo().equals(title)` se evalúe a `true`.

Lo primero que debes hacer es asegurarte de la lista de preguntas que te comento no tenga más de un pregunta con el mismo título.

No obstante puede también usar un `break` dentro del `if` para terminar el `for` cuando encuentre la primera coincidencia.

```
for(Pregunta p: stack.getListaPreguntas()) {
    if(p.getTitulo().equals(title)){
        QuestionView questionWindow = new QuestionView(p, stack); 
        questionWindow.setVisible(true);

        break;// forzar la finalización del bucle
    }
}
```